# Jquery: How to get the latest object to pass through my events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I have 3 event triggers in my code, but they all get activated individually per mouse click. But the issue I'm running into is the click event uses OLD or the FIRST data passed through to it in my function, rather than the LAST object when the event was triggered.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

Here is a example:

First click (event) on position 1.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    removeSkillButton(SKILL 1);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

Second click (event) on position 1.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    removeSkillButton(SKILL 2);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

Third click (event) on position 2.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    removeSkillButton(SKILL 2);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    removeSkillButton(SKILL 1);
    addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

It keeps using old data stored from my past clicking sessions, rather than using the latest object or click event passed to it! How do I write in javascript / jquery, that I want to use the LAST or LATEST object, not the previously stored ones??? Sorry if I am not descriptive, I been trying to find a solution to this for the past 5 hours.

Comment: Are you trying to use different `click` event handlers, or different logic within same event handler, for each click at an element, in sequential order?

Comment: There is a menu system that gives you 3 options. You can click 1 of the 3, but this is a game, so this menu continually pops up. The only thing that really is different is position selection (position 1, 2 or 3). However, it seems that the event is storing previously old clicks. 

Example, clicks on position 1 will be saved for position 2 & 3, thus resulting in errors and passing objects of position 1, rather than the latest object from click 2 or 3.

Comment: You  using the same functions in each `click` handler. How does `#position1` get clicked twice where you are using `.one()`? Are there elements having duplicate `id`s in `document`? What is `object`? Can you create a stacksnippet or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate issue?